Dynamic TypeScript Function handler with optional arguments based on function name
I have a set of helper functions that prepare database queries. Some have arguments, some don't. I'm struggling with writing the type of the function that runs those helper functions and then executes them.
TS Playground Link
type PreparedQuery = {
  query: string;
  params?: string[] | null
}

interface Queries {
  foo: {
    returns: {
      col1: string;
      col2: string;
      col3: number | null;
    }
    args: {
      arg1: string;
    }
  }
  bar: {
    returns: Database['public']['Tables']['table_b']
    args: null;
  }
}

const foo = ({arg1} : Queries['foo']['args']) : PreparedQuery => {
  //do stuff
  return {query: "SELECT ...........", params: ['xyz']}
}

const bar = () : PreparedQuery => {
  return {query: "SELECT ......"}
}

const QueryFunctions = {
  foo,
  bar
}

interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      table_a: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
      }
      table_b: {
        id: number;
        status: 0 | 1;
        create_time: Date;
        update_time: Date;
      }
    }
  }
}



class DBClient {
  pool: Pool // PGPool

  constructor() {
    this.pool = new Pool();
  }

  closePool() { this.pool.end() }


  async executeQuery({ query, params }: PreparedQuery) {
    const res = params ? await this.pool.query(query, params) : await this.pool.query(query);
    return res.rows
  }

  getQuery<Q extends keyof Queries>(queryName : Q, args : Queries[Q]['args']) : Queries[Q]['returns']
  getQuery<Q extends keyof Queries>(queryName : Q) : Queries[Q]['returns']
  async getQuery(queryName : keyof Queries, args? : Queries[typeof queryName]['args'] ){
      let f : PreparedQuery = args ?  QueryFunctions[queryName](args) : QueryFunctions[queryName]();
      return await this.executeQuery(f)
  }

}

The problem is around the getQuery signature. The intended use of this would be something like this
const x = new DBClient()
const barResponse = await x.getQuery('bar')
const fooResponse = await x.getQuery('foo', {arg1: 'something'})

Basically the point is to be able to easily extend the number of functions and get the TS autocomplete and safety that it'll only let me call functions that exist and require the correct arguments (if any).
The issuse i'm having is that for functions without arguments like bar in this case, TS is complaining that QueryFunctions[queryName]() expects an argument even though calling getQuery('bar') without arguments is no problem.
The other typescript issue here is that getQuery('foo') which should require an argument is not complaining that it doesn't have one here.
Simplification Update
new TS Playground Link
interface Queries {
  foo: {
    returns: {
      col1: string;
      col2: string;
      col3: number | null;
    }
    args: {
      arg1: string;
    }
  }
  bar: {
    returns: string
    args: null;
  }
}

const foo = ({ arg1 }: Queries['foo']['args']) => {
  return { query: "SELECT col1, col2, col3 from ", params: [arg1] }
}

const bar = () => {
  return { query: "SELECT * FROM table_b" }
}

const QueryFunctions = {foo,bar}



type QueryName = keyof Queries
type Args<T extends QueryName> = Queries[T]["args"] extends null ? [T] : [T, Queries[T]["args"]]

function query<T extends QueryName>(...args: Args<T>): Queries[T]["returns"] {
  
  const [fname, fargs] = args;
  const preparedQuery = fargs ? QueryFunctions[fname](fargs) : QueryFunctions[fname]() // this is causing a TS error but not a functional error
  console.log(preparedQuery)
  
  // Here you would return the real value, I cast to not get type error.
  return 123 as unknown as Queries[T]["returns"];
}

query("foo", { arg1: "123" })
query("foo") // correctly complaining about missing argument
query("bar")

I simplified the original question (using Felix's example) to highlight the issue of handling the calling of these helper functions with/without arguments. foo requires an argument object and calling query("foo") correctly complaining about the missing argument and correctly tells you what it needs. Likewise bar which does not have any arguments shows no type errors when calling query("bar").
Since the appropriate helper function needs to be called inside the query function I figured this should work:
const [fname, fargs] = args;
const preparedQuery = fargs ? QueryFunctions[fname](fargs) : QueryFunctions[fname]()

And it works when executed but TypeScript complains that it expects an argument for QueryFunctions[fname]() even though when fargs is null because when query('bar') is run, the bar helper function is run which does not have any arguments and TS should know this based on that Queries[T]["args"] extends null check.
Like I said, it runs fine but has that TS error, so how can I resolve the TS error here?

• Why are you overloading the call signatures as if the function is synchronous? Is that just a typo or part of the question in some way? • Have you made an attempt to encode the relationship between the functions and the input? It seems you might as well just use type assertions if you're overloading. So far this code seems pretty muddled so maybe you're just asking for how to write it correctly instead of how to fix your particular attempt?

see prev comment. I'm trying to fix this and I've got this far but the code you're not asking about is weird. • Please add more than just foo and bar with differing i/o or the example won't show the problem properly. • You're returning an array from executeQuery() but the returns properties nowhere match arrays. Why? • What's with Database and the indexed access types? It's just indirection that distracts from your main question, right? Could you fix these issues to be a [mre] and then let me know if my approach addresses the question so we can proceed?

Please edit your code so it asks a single question and does not appear as a series of updates. Interested parties can see history; adding more code doesn't count as a simplification.  Given your current code I would write it this way (noting that it's still doing weird stuff with the return type; why not just have the function return void instead of pretending you can access "return:"). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

hi @jcalz. Thanks for the update. This works great. Please make it an answer and I can tick it. I'm not going to edit the question down though since it isn't a series of questions but all part of one problem -- the dynamic parameters typing based on function name AND the ability to call the query function prep without the type error.

It reads like a series of questions. You can have multiple requirements without needing multiple sections, the second of which reads “simplification update”.  Future readers would benefit from having a question post that reads like a single question. Please do make the edit. I'm also concerned about the time gap between my asking my question above and your response. Is there any guarantee that if I write an answer you will respond in a timely manner so that the content doesn’t page out of my brain again?

Something like this could solve this:
type Args<T extends QueryName> = Queries[T]["args"] extends null ? [T] : [T, Queries[T]["args"]]

Here is the full Typescript Playground example, (a bit simplified).

Thank you very much Felix! This gets me mostly there but TS throws a type error when I try to use this setup to actually call a function with/without arguments. I updated the question and TS playground link to highlight the problem
